# Rails, Koala & Facebook - Post Image to wall and keep track of like count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api, koala

I am developing an rails appplication that is communicating heavily with Facebook.
The concept is that users can upload images and there will be a kind of a gallery with thumbnails of these images and a "like-count" indicator.
I am using the `koala` gem.

I successfully posted an image to my wall like this:

```
  if current_user && session[:fb_token]
    @user_graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(session[:fb_token])
  end
  @user_graph.put_picture(@post.photo.url)
```

In my `_post.html.erb` I do something like this:

```
<div class="fb-like left_float" data-href="<%= post.photo.url %>" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="170" data-show-faces="false" data-font="segoe ui"></div>
```

If I just include this html snippet from facebook, I don't get the right results, as this points to the same uploaded image but not to the post created before. I think I need some kind of post_id from the Facebook post that i created before?

Any ideas ?

**update**

the put_picture method returns the following:

```
id: '109668002508542'
post_id: '100003960282996_109668032508539'
```

but when I check these IDs using http://graph.facebook.com/109668002508542 or

```
@user_graph.get_object('109668002508542')
```

I get no information, no likes and just a 'false'

Answer (score 1):

So, you're looking to get a count of the likes for a photo that you uploaded? You shouldn't use the like button for this. You can use the `get_connections` method to retrieve the number of likes for the page. Try something like

```
<div>
  <%= @user_graph.get_connections(@the_post_id_from_put_picture, "likes") likes
</div>
```

Remember to make sure you have the correct permissions to access the objects. Check your permissions with the OAuth flow in Koala https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki/OAuth

Comment: how would I get the @the_post_id_from_put_picture ? is it being created when I upload something ?

Comment: This should be getting returned from the put_picture method. See https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki/Uploading-Photos-and-Videos for examples.

Comment: thanks connor, I tried that and it does return something. Just I can't get any data from the returned IDs. Updated my question--- any other idea, maybe ?

Comment: No problem. I updated my question with a note on permissions. Try the Graph API Explorer tool, it's a great way to test permissions and API return values without having to write code https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=109668002508542

Comment: Thanks.. but why do I just get a 'false'. you think it is a permissions problem ?

Comment: Yes, usually that's a permissions problem.